# Change the public key of the user who is used to connect with ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

i want to change the public key in the authorized_keys file of a client with ansible. I do that by deleting the authorized_keys file (module file) and create the new file (module lineinfile).

Complete code:

```
 name: "{{ansibleuser_username}} : Remove authorized keys file when exist"
    file:
      path: "{{ansibleuser_home_dir}}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      state: absent

  - name: "{{ansibleuser_username}} : Set public key"
    lineinfile:
      path: "{{ansibleuser_home_dir}}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      owner: "{{ansibleuser_username}}"
      group: "{{ansibleuser_username}}"
      mode: 0600
      line: "{{ansibleuser_public_key}}"
      create: yes
    when: "ansibleuser_public_key is defined"
```

The problem is, that the connection is lost, when deleting the authorized_keys file (no surprise). Any idea how to prevent this? A workaround should be, to do this with a bash script in one step and make this task the last one in the play. But that is also improper, because the play will have a fail.

Another idea was to create a cron Job which replaces the keys in a minute and delete itselfs. But feels also not so nice.

I really think there is a build-in solution, i didn't find?!

Regards

Dave

Comment: The built-in solution: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html

Comment: If the built-in solution still gives you trouble changing your own user key and produces connection errors, I replied to [a very similar question](/a/72837761/9401096) a few days ago. Just change `ansible_password` to `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` in that answer and I believe it will meet your requirement. Note: you should still use the builtin solution and just add the `async` part.